# Senah 4.2.3 - How to create a common module

Tags: extjs

I'm working on a Sencha ExtJS 4.2.3 project where we have n number of packages.

We have 10 different packages

```
For example
packages - folder
 -> package 1 - app.js
 -> package 2 - app.js
 -> package 3 - app.js
 -> package 4 - app.js
 -> package 5 - app.js
 -> package 6 - app.js
 -> package 7 - app.js
 -> package 8 - app.js
 -> package 9 - app.js
 -> package 10 -app.js
```

Each package has the app.js file, which is begin referred in their specific jsp files files, so once the spring controller called the ExtJS package will be called respectively

**Problem is**
Now the client requires a common functionalities which should be available in all pages, so in order to avail that functionalities i have to include that functionalities in all the packages which is not good.

How can we create a common functionalities which can be used in all the packages without modifying them.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same requiremeny.You can keep your common functionalities in another folder & include those common functionality files(stores,models,controller,view) in each app.js.

Comment: That way i know already, but it will hard to modify every time all the packages. Looking for an alternative solution to fix is problem